# Dataframe выбор большего

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Был предыдущий вопрос, на который был дан ответ.

В датафрейме есть неизвестное кол-во столбцов.
Есть столбец res['number'] (это не индекс). Есть остальные.
В каждой строке значения.
Как построчно получить ответ на вопрос - какое название столбца в каждой строке соответствует самой большому значению в строке.

```
['number'] ['a'] ['b'] ['c']
1            5     4.1   3
2            2.4   3     3
3            3     6    6
4            1     4.8   8.7
```

А итог по строкам так

```
for i in ...:
    print(...)

    а (т.к. 5 больше 4.1 и 3)
    b (любое - пусть первое т.к. равны)
    b
    c
```

Ответ:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 4.1, 3],
                   [2, 2.4, 3, 3],
                   [3, 3, 6, 6],
                   [4, 1, 4.8, 8.7]
                   ],
                  columns=['number', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
for indexRows in range(df.shape[0]):
    print(df.columns[np.argmax(df.loc[indexRows])])
```

А как получить тот же результат, если некоторые числа будут в датафрейме
отрицательные, но считаем их за положительные? То есть из 10,2,-5,-11 большее будет -11.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[-1, 5, -4.1, -3],
                   [2, -2.4, 3, -3],
                   [3, 3, -6, 6],
                   [4, 1, -4.8, 8.7]
                   ],
                  columns=['number', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: выглядит как учебное, но нет, это не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **df.columns** - возвращает имена полей
2. **df.columns[i]** -  возвращает имя i-ого поля (по индексу)
3. **np.argmax** - возвращает индекс максимального элемента (возвращается индекс элемента с первым вхождением)
4. **df.loc[i]** - выводит i-ую строку
5. **df.shape[0]** - выводит количество строк

Дополнение:

6. **df = df.abs()** - сделает все числа в датафрейме *df* абсолютными.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 4.1, 3],
                   [2, 2.4, 3, 3],
                   [3, 3, 6, 6],
                   [4, 1, 4.8, 8.7]
                   ],
                  columns=['number', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
for indexRows in range(df.shape[0]):
    print(df.columns[np.argmax(df.loc[indexRows])])
```

Выведет:

```
a
b
b
c
```

Comment: @ssoop, df = df.abs() - сделает все числа в датафрейме абсолютными

Comment: а если весь датафрейм не могу преобразовать в abs() т.к. он нужен (датафрейм) для других целей?

Comment: @ssoop, сделайте временную копию (например: **df_copy = df.abs()** ), которую сделаете абсолютной.

Answer (score 2):

Без циклов

```
>>> df.idxmax(axis=1)

0    a
1    b
2    b
3    c
```